# Ad networks that let you run your own cookie targeting

Tags: advertising, cookie, ad-targeting

We've got some proprietary cookie targeting software which we are developing to help deliver better targeted ads.

We don't have a group of publishers, nor particularly want to go and build our own network as this is almost as difficult as building the targeting software.

Are there any networks out there that will let us run our own cookie targeting script on their network and publishers.

Comment: What do you mean by 'cookie targeting'? Do you mean you've created your own models for pricing impressions? It sounds like you are in the area of real-time bidding, so I'd take a look at some Demand Side Platforms to see if there are any APIs, etc...

Comment: @brendon, by 'cookie targeting' i mean by reading the different cookies a user has in their browser and then serving them ads based upon the analysis of those cookies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sam, what you are trying to do is to read third party cookies. I'm afraid, that is something nobody can do, nor are ad networks able to do that.

Each domain can only read its own cookies and there is no way to have domain A read cookies set by domain B or domain C.

More infomation about how cookies work, the differences between first-party and third-party cookies, their restrictions and what is possible and what isn't, can be found [here](http://www.bobulous.org.uk/misc/third-party-cookies.html), [here](http://www.opentracker.net/article/third-party-cookies-vs-first-party-cookies), [here (nice illustrations too)](http://anantgarg.com/2012/02/18/busting-the-cookies-and-privacy-myth/) and [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie) of course.

Comment: ahh, i must have got the wrong end of the stick, i thought this is how people like Quantcast were able to put people into audiences, i also thought that this was the basis of re targeting ?

Comment: The basis of re-targeting is reading someone's own cookies. Basically provider A sets a retargeting cookie on website B. Provider A (on another site) reads his own cookie and is able to retarget based on that cookie. I also wrote an answer on how Quantcast segment traffic here: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/47077/quantcast-reporting/47079#47079...